# How to disable standard performance counters in Application Insights?

Tags: .net, azure-application-insights

Standard performance counters in Application Insights generate too much volume. How can I disable them and only report my own counters + some standard ones (but not all), or just reduce sample frequency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding this answer for asp.netcore users. modify your startup.cs as shown. You have two options. First completely disables the perf counters.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    var serviceDescriptor = services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ImplementationType == typeof(PerformanceCollectorModule));
    services.Remove(serviceDescriptor);
}
```

or second removes individual counters and you can add your own if you want later.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{

    var modules = app.ApplicationServices.GetServices<ITelemetryModule>();
    var perfModule = modules.OfType<PerformanceCollectorModule>().First();
    perfModule.DefaultCounters.Clear();

}
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case adding counters to Counters didn't affected the default counters so both sets mine and default was reported. Fortunately the collector is [open source](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/2a681f5399a6aaee554fa2d93a1d6447a8402fe1/Src/PerformanceCollector/Shared/PerformanceCollectorModule.cs#L44) and there is a clear clue what you need to do in order remove them. Just define an empty `DefaultCounters` like this:

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
    <DefaultCounters/>
    <Counters>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="YOUR COUNTER"/>
    </Counters>
</Add>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the latest .NET SDK, you can configure the performance counters or sampling ratio via the [applicationinsights.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-configuration-with-applicationinsights-config) file.

In the [Telemetry Processors section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-configuration-with-applicationinsights-config#telemetry-processors-aspnet), you can set adaptive sampling by adding:

```
<TelemetryProcessors>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
    <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
  </Add>
</TelemetryProcessors>
```

Setting specific performence counters can be in the [Telemetry Modules section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-configuration-with-applicationinsights-config#telemetry-modules-aspnet) (see also [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/04/01/application-insights-choose-your-own-performance-counters/)), for example:

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
  <Counters>
    <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Handle Count" ReportAs="Process handle count" />
  </Counters>      
</Add>
```

Removing the *PerfCounterCollector* type will disable performance counters collection altogether.

Asaf

Comment: Will manual setting of <Counters> disable standard ones (CPU, Memory, etc)?